# How to make a div a link

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a div with a background image, which is separated by two divs inside of the original div. How do I make the two divs clickable links that open in a new tab?

I searched around and the only advice I understood was to use JavaScript, but that wont work on all browsers will it?

HTML:

```
<div class="SocialMedia">

    <div class="icon1" onclick="location.href='https://www.facebook.com/DRC.Race.Leathers';" target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
    <div class="icon2" onclick="location.href='https://twitter.com/DRC_Leathers';" target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>

    <span>Make sure to visit our social media pages to keep up to date with the latest from DRC</span>

</div> <!-- End of SocialMedia -->
```

CSS:

```
    .SocialMedia {
background-color: #000;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
width: 440px;
height: 330px;
background-image: url('Images/Social-Media.png');
border: 5px solid #000;
text-align: center;
font-size: 10;
color: #fff;
position: relative;
}

.SocialMedia span {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}

.icon1 {
width: 180px;
height: 180px;
float: left;
}

.icon2 {
width: 180px;
height: 180px;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Replace the `DIV` with `A`?

Comment: You need to use `window.open` instead of `location.href` to open in a new window, but pounding a round peg through a square hole and making a div behave like a hyperlink is a bad idea.  It will kill usability by disabled users, stop web crawlers/indexers, etc.  All in all a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I realised my errors

HTML:

```
<div class="SocialMedia">

    <a href="https://twitter.com/DRC_Leathers" target="_blank"><div class="icon1"></div></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/DRC_Leathers" target="_blank"><div class="icon2"></div></a>

    <span>Make sure to visit our social media pages to keep up to date with the latest from DRC</span>

</div> <!-- End of SocialMedia -->
```

The CSS stayed the same